# How to give permissions to user?

Tags: permission-sets, sharing-rule

I Have three users with respective roles role hierarchy is CEO --> Manager --> Subordinate. When i share records to subordinate records will see manager because he is superior to subordinate. How it possible if i share records to subordinate records will not see manager how can i achieve this scenario.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want for only the `Owner` to be able to access records, you'll need to set the Org-Wide defaults to `Private`.

To achieve this, go to:

> Setup > Security Controls > Sharing Settings

Find your object, set the drop-down to `Private` and make sure `Grant Access Using Hierarchies` is unticked.

That's the part that allows managers to see subordinates records.

Answer (score 0):

In sharing settings, the OWD of the object should be private and grant access using Hierarchies checkbox should be disabled.